# I need to take the information from them and write to the variable "Vidpovid". How can this be done?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a problem. I am creating "input" fields dynamically. I need to take the information from them and write to the variable "Vidpovid". How can this be done?

Code HTML

```
<div class="form-group" id="input">
        <button type="button" onclick="createNewInput()">new input</button>

        <input type="number" id="1" class="form-control" /><br />
        <ol id="base-list"></ol>
        <br />

        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Less_Check.Vidpovid" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Code JS

```
let id = 2;

function createNewInput() {
  let addNewInput = true;

  for(let i = 1; i < id; i++)
    {
      if(document.getElementById(i).value == "")
        {addNewInput = false;}
    }

  if(addNewInput)
  {
      let baseList = document.getElementById('base-list')
      let newInput = document.createElement("input");
      newInput.setAttribute("type", "number");
      newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

      newInput.setAttribute("id", id);
      id++;
      baseList.append(newInput);
      baseList.append(document.createElement("br"));
  }
  else
  {
      alert("error");
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Artem, for your js, it seems to judge if the input null or nor, if it does not contains any value, will not add new input. If contains value, will add the new input. Do you want to set the input value to the hidden `Vidpovid`? If so, how is the value like if multiple input with number, like `1,2,...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo you could follow:

```
<script>
    let id = 2;

    function createNewInput() {
        let addNewInput = true;

        for (let i = 1; i < id; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(i).value == "") { addNewInput = false; }
        }

        if (addNewInput) {
            let baseList = document.getElementById('base-list')
            let newInput = document.createElement("input");
            newInput.setAttribute("type", "number");
            newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

            newInput.setAttribute("id", id);
            id++;
            baseList.append(newInput);
            baseList.append(document.createElement("br"));
            
        }
        else {
            alert("error");
        }

       //add the following code to set the value for hidden input..
        const arr = Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]'),
          input => input.value
        ).filter(n=>n);
        document.getElementById("Less_Check_Vidpovid").value = arr.join(",");
    }
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks. It helped me! Maybe you can tell me how to make it so that I can specify fractional numbers? For example: "1.2" or "5.77".
The "number" type only allows integers but it doesn't work for me :(
Need to do your own inspection?

Comment: Hi @Artem, if you want to use double/float type number, you need use the text type input.